# How to randomly select and bind data columns based on their median values in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, selection, data-manipulation

I have two dataframes in wide format. Each of the columns is a time series of page hits for various wikipedia articles.

```
set.seed(123)
library(tidyr)

time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9

wiki_1 <- data.frame(
  W = sample(1:1000,10,replace = T),
  X = sample(1:100,10,replace = T),
  Y = sample(1:10,10,replace = T),
  Z = sample(1:10,10, replace = T)
)

wiki_2 <- data.frame(
  A = sample(500:1000,10,replace = T),
  B = sample(90:100,10,replace = T),
  C = sample(1:10,10,replace = T),
  D = sample(1:10,10,replace = T)
)
```

I want to combine one of the columns from the first dataset (`wiki_1`) with n  columns from the second dataset (`wiki_2`). But this selection should be based on how close the median values of the columns in `wiki_2` are to those in `wiki_1` e.g. by order of magnitude.

In this example, for n = 2, Y should be matched with C and D because of how close their median values are.

```
median(wiki_1$Y) # 7
median(wiki_2$C) # 6
median(wiki_2$D) # 4.5
```

I'm not sure how to implement the difference in median values criterion to get the desired result.

Additionally, it would be useful to be able to randomly sample from the columns in `wiki_2` that satisfy the criterion as my real dataset has many more columns.

This is what I'm working with so far:

```
df <- zoo(cbind(subset(wiki_1,select="Y"), 
                   subset(wiki_2,select=c("C","D"))),time)
```

Comment: so you want to check the median for a column in wiki_1 and compare how close it is to the median in each column in `wiki_2` and based on a ranking criteria (top 2 closest in your example) you want to combine them. Additionally you want to subset the columns in `wiki_2` that satisfy the criteria so as to match the number of rows in the columns specified in `wiki_1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after. I added a column to `wiki_2` in order to allow more than 2 matches to show the random selection of matching columns.

```
set.seed(123)
library(tidyr)

time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9

wiki_1 <- data.frame(
  W = sample(1:1000,10,replace = T),
  X = sample(1:100,10,replace = T),
  Y = sample(1:10,10,replace = T),
  Z = sample(1:10,10, replace = T)
)

wiki_2 <- data.frame(
  A = sample(500:1000,10,replace = T),
  B = sample(90:100,10,replace = T),
  C = sample(1:10,10,replace = T),
  D = sample(1:10,10,replace = T),
  E = sample(1:20,10,replace = T)
)


selectColsByMedian <- function(df1, df2, ref_v, n_v, cutoff_v) {
  #' Select Columns By Median
  #' @description Select any number of columns from a test data.frame whose median value is
  #' close to the median value of a specified column from a reference data.frame. "Close to"
  #' is determined as the absolute value of the difference in medians being less thant he specified cutoff.
  #' Outputs a new data.frame containing the reference data.frame's test column and all matching columns
  #' from the test data.frame
  #' @param df1 reference data.frame
  #' @param df2 test data.frame
  #' @param ref_v column from reference data.frame to test against
  #' @param n_v number of columns from df2 to select
  #' @param cutoff_v value to use to determine if test columns' medians are close enough
  #' @return data.frame with 1 column from df1 and matching columns from df2

  ## Get median of ref
  med_v <- median(df1[,ref_v], na.rm = T)

  ## Get other medians
  otherMed_v <- apply(wiki_2, 2, function(x) median(x, na.rm = T))

  ## Get differences
  medDiff_v <- sapply(otherMed_v, function(x) abs(med_v - x))

  ## Get whoever is within range (and order them)
  inRange_v <- sort(medDiff_v[medDiff_v < cutoff_v])
  inRangeCols_v <- names(inRange_v)

  ## Select random sample, if needed
  if (length(inRangeCols_v) > n_v){
    whichRandom_v <- sample(1:length(inRangeCols_v), size = n_v, replace = F)
  } else {
    whichRandom_v <- 1:length(inRangeCols_v)
  }
  finalCols_v <- inRangeCols_v[whichRandom_v]

  ## Final output
  out_df <- cbind(df1[,ref_v], df2[,finalCols_v])
  colnames(out_df) <- c(ref_v, finalCols_v)

  ## Return
  return(out_df)
} # selectColsByMedian

### 3 matching columns, select 2
match3pick2_df <- selectColsByMedian(df1 = wiki_1, df2 = wiki_2, ref_v = "Y", n_v = 2, cutoff_v = 12)
match3pick2_df2 <- selectColsByMedian(df1 = wiki_1, df2 = wiki_2, ref_v = "Y", n_v = 2, cutoff_v = 12)

### 2 matching columns, select 2
match2pick2_df <- selectColsByMedian(df1 = wiki_1, df2 = wiki_2, ref_v = "Y", n_v = 2, cutoff_v = 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, I've added more columns to `wiki_2` to allow for subsetting (but it works if `ncols(wiki_1) == ncols(wiki_2)`.

```
set.seed(123)

wiki_1 <- data.frame(
  W = sample(1:1000,10,replace = T),
  X = sample(1:100,10,replace = T),
  Y = sample(1:10,10,replace = T),
  Z = sample(1:10,10, replace = T)
)

wiki_2 <- data.frame(
  A = sample(500:1000,100,replace = T),
  B = sample(90:100,100,replace = T),
  C = sample(1:10,100,replace = T),
  D = sample(1:10,100,replace = T)
)

combineMedianComp <- function(data1, data2, col, n){
  if(nrow(data1) > nrow(data2)) stop("Rows in 'data2' need to be greater or equal to rows in 'data1'")

  medRef <- median(data1[[col]], na.rm = T, ) # median of desired column

  medComp <- sapply(data2, function(x){abs(medRef - median(x, na.rm = T))}) # vector with medians for each columns in data2 ('wiki_2')

  cols <- names(sort(medComp)[seq_len(n)]) # sort this vector in ascending order, select top n

  d2 <- data2[, c(cols)] # select columns in data2 that have medians closest to 'medRef'

  d2 <- d2[sample(seq_len(nrow(d2)), size = nrow(data1), replace = F), ] # subset column as to match those in data1

  # merge data
  res <- do.call(cbind, list(data1[col], d2)) 

  return(res)
}


combineMedianComp(data1 = wiki_1, data2 = wiki_2, col = "Y", n = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9

close_median <- function(df1, df2, to_match = NULL){

    # get median
    m <- median(df1[[to_match]])

    # get difference of median from other data 
    mat_cols <-  apply(df2, 2, function(x) abs(m - median(x)))

    # get top 2 matched column
    cols <- sort(names(sort(v)[1:2]))

    return(cbind(df1[to_match], df2[cols], row.names=time))

}

close_median(wiki_1, wiki_2, 'Y')

            Y  C  D
2009-01-01  8  9 10
2009-01-02  7  8  1
2009-01-03  1  7  7
2009-01-04 10  3 10
2009-01-05  2  1  1
2009-01-06  3 10  3
2009-01-07  6  2  3
2009-01-08  5  8 10
2009-01-09  3  8  5
2009-01-10 10  8  3
```